# Error in opencv 3.1.0 using SURF

Tags: c++, opencv

I am new to opencv and using version 3.1.0 . I am trying to build a simple tutorial from this link : http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d7/d66/tutorial_feature_detection.html#gsc.tab=0

But an error occurs :  opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp: No such file or directory

How is that possible ? Can you help me ?

Comment: You need to install the OpenCV development libraries and header files. How? That should hopefully be documented.

Comment: My opencv libraries work fine so far in other programs e.g. optical flow calculation etc. Why is there a problem ?

Comment: Dunno. What's different with this program? From the little info you provided, there's little else than the general advise I can give you.

Comment: As far as i know , the include libraries are different , because i need to use the SURF object . However the include file suggested in the site  does not exist ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution. I had to uninstall the library and install it again, like described in this link : http://embedonix.com/articles/image-processing/installing-opencv-3-1-0-on-ubuntu/